# Windows 8 application deployment without uploading to windows store?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

i have developed a windows 8 application using visual studio express edition 2012, i want to install that application on a windows 8 tablet

i dont want to upload the application to windows store, it is only for a group of people,how will install the app packages in the windows 8 tablet

please help

Comment: Not entirely impossible, there's an option called "enterprise sideloading".  It will set you back about ten grand. That's usually where it ends.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Store menu and select "Create App Packages" (or similar - I am doing it in full VS, I think it should be similar in Express). Create a package and select an option to not save it to the store. When it is done - you should get a link to a folder where the package is saved together with a PowerShell script to install it. Just copy the whole package to a machine where you want to deploy it and run the script on that machine.

This is a developer option that requires typing in your free developer account credentials on the test machine, but might be easier than the other option of enterprise sideloading, which I am not too familiar with.

Comment: is the process same for windows 8 tablet also

Comment: Yes, you copy the files and run the script, then registering the device with a dev account if not already registered and then it just runs.

Comment: I’ve tried and this way works. But it says that the certificate will be expired at some time. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: Yes, my method is a kind of developer preview option meant for developers or their customers wanting to try out the app on a device. For your scenario you might need to do enterprise deployment. Maybe [this article](http://www.irisclasson.com/2013/02/13/windows-store-app-enterprise-deployment-mini-guide/) would help you.